# Best way to store what type of possible classes are available?

Tags: c#

Currently I'm doing this:

```
public static class IngredientDataStorage
{

    public static List<Ingredient> GetIngredientList()
    {
    List<Ingredient> availIngredientsList = new List<Ingredient>()
       {
        new Butter(), new Cinnamon(), new Chocolate()
       };
    return availIngredientsList;
    }

   public static Dictionary<int, Ingredient> GetIngredientDictionary()
    {
       Dictionary<int, Ingredient> availIngDict = new Dictionary<int, Ingredient>()
      {
       {3, new Chocolate() },
       {2, new Butter() },
       {4, new Cinnamon() }
      };
      return availIngDict;
   }


public static List<int> GetIDList()
  {
    var IDList = new List<int>();
    foreach (Ingredient ingredient in GetIngredientList())
    {
        IDList.Add(ingredient.ID);
    }
    return IDList;
   }

public static void PrintAvailIngredients()
  {
    List<Ingredient> ingredientList = IngredientDataStorage.GetIngredientList();

    foreach (Ingredient ingredient in ingredientList)
    {
        ingredient.PrintInfo();
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to store data about what available ingredients there are than doing something like this? In this case I have 3 ingredients - butter, cinnamon, and chocolate. I store them in a list here, a dictionary here, and also have a method to give the IDs of these objects as well as to print out all the ingredients to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main principle to apply is that for a given type of change, you want to only need to change one part of your code. Google "Single Responsibility Principle" and "Open/Closed Principle." Your list could probably be derived from your dictionary, or vice versa, for example, to avoid duplication (although as your code stands, there doesn't appear to be any correlation between the order of items in your list, the order of items in the dictionary, or the order of the IDs associated with those values--is that on purpose?).

There are a lot of ways to approach this, and which one works best will depend largely on what this will be used for, and the likely reasons for change in your code. For example:

- Consider how you want ID values to be represented. What happens if two different developers are adding new Ingredient classes at the same time, and end up using the same ID value.
- Consider using reflection to scan your entire assembly for ingredients, so adding a new class is all that's required to add an ingredient to your data structures.
- If the different ingredients only have different *values* for their properties, they probably shouldn't be separate classes at all. You can just have a list of `Ingredient`s declared somewhere, with each one assigned an ID, a Name, etc.
- If the code doesn't need to do anything different depending on which specific ingredients are used, you may want to store that list in a database or a file somewhere rather than in the code itself.
- If the IDs need to be persistent, you'll need to use a storage mechanism that keeps the ID values consistent. If they don't, you could assign a unique ID value when you read/scan the different ingredient options, and avoid assigning each one an explicit number in your code or data store.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! What is reflection?

Comment: [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) allows you to write code that inspects things like classes, properties, and methods, at runtime. So you could write a simple LINQ query, for example, that gives you all the classes that implement a certain interface, or which have a certain custom attribute on them. Then you can call the constructors of those classes to create instances of them.